# Why can i not call COUNT on a varray column in a select statement using oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I have a simple array type definition like this

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "LIST_OF_NAMES_T" IS  VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2 (100);
```

Now I have a column **items** of type **LIST_OF_NAMES_T** in my table **TABLE1**

Why am I getting an error when selecting the count of the array in a select statement like this:

```
SELECT items.COUNT FROM TABLE1;
```

Oracle tells me

*ORA-00904: "items"."COUNT ": invalid identifier*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.2 documentation: [Using Collection Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i27396)

> The following apply to collection methods:
>
> - **Collection methods cannot be called from SQL statements.**
>
> ...

11.2 documentation: [Collection Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00508)

> A collection method invocation can appear anywhere that an invocation
>   of a PL/SQL subprogram of its type (function or procedure) can appear,
>   **except in a SQL statement**.

Versions before 12c:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "LIST_OF_NAMES_T" IS  VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2 (100);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table table1(c1 LIST_OF_NAMES_T);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values(LIST_OF_NAMES_T('A', 'B'));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

SQL> create function f1(p_list_of_names list_of_names_t) return number as
  2  begin
  3    return p_list_of_names.count;
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> select f1(items) from table1;

 F1(ITEMS)
----------
         2
```

In 12c and later, you can define functions on the fly, so this also works:

```
SQL> with function f2(p_list_of_names list_of_names_t) return number as
  2  begin
  3   return p_list_of_names.count;
  4  end;
  5  select f2(items) from table1;
  6  /

 F2(ITEMS)
----------
         2
```